# Get mouse position during drag in OnGiveFeedback override

Tags: c#, html, wpf, drag-and-drop

I have a project that is using WPF Drag and Drop built in functionality. I'm using the OnGiveFeedback event override to change the cursor when the draggable item is inside a droppable item.

My issue is that the control I'm trying to isolate the drag and drop to is embedded in an area that also contains HTML on the sides. When I drag over the HTML area, my cursor changes like it is over a drop area.

I'm trying to remedy this by getting the mouse position when my DragDropEffect =  DragDropEffect.Move inside my OnGiveFeedback override, and making sure the mouse is still within the bounds of my control.

I can't seem to find a way to get the mouse position from inside this override. Mouse.Position is returning the point where my Drag started so I'd assume the mouse events get blocked once a drag operation starts.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Code Snippet:

```
    protected override void OnGiveFeedback(GiveFeedbackEventArgs e)
    {
        // These Effects values are set in the drop target's
        // DragOver event handler.
        if (e.Effects.HasFlag(DragDropEffects.Move) || e.Effects.HasFlag(DragDropEffects.Copy))
        {
            Mouse.SetCursor(Cursors.Cross);
        }
        else
        {
            Mouse.SetCursor(Cursors.Arrow);
        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you override OnDragEnter and OnDragLeave and change the cruser from there.